# ARM inline assembly - input operand constraint contains '='

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

This is my current code:

```
void int32hex(u32 val, char *out) {
    asm("rev %[dst], %[src]" :: [dst]"=r"(val), [src]"r"(val));

    binhex((u8*)&val, 4, out);
}
```

My idea is to take the argument `val`, flip it (endianness) using the `rev` instruction, and then pass it on.

From what I've read, the above code seems to be correct, the destination register has the `=r` flag, which implies that the register can be written to. However, when run though GCC, I get the error: input operand constraint contains '='

If I change the flag to simply `r` then it will compile fine, but the value of `val` does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you what is going wrong -- the `=` constraint applies only to outputs, not inputs, and your asm pattern has two inputs (one confusingly called 'dst') and no outputs.  You probably meant to have 'dst' be an output:

```
asm("rev %[dst], %[src]" : [dst]"=r"(val) : [src]"r"(val));
```

Comment: `asm("rev %[swap], %[swap]" : [swap] "=r" (val) : "0" (val));` might be better.  You can use the "0" specifier to say the input is the same as a given output; this will sometimes generate better code as the register will be the same.  Also, the *src/dst* is confusing as you note.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Using a `0` constraint will force it to use the same register for src and dst, which may require an extra move to get them into the same place.  Using separate input and output constraints allows the compiler to use the same register or different registers, whichever is better.  In this specific case, it's irrelevant, but it will never be better to use `0`.

Comment: @artlessnoise: `dst` is just a identifier name for the operand register, so can't be calculated in any way.  `0` will require an extra move if `val` is already in a particular register (perhaps an argument register) and is next needed in a different register (eg, the return value register)

Comment: gcc does live range splitting even if you disable SSA (as any useful compiler does), so the fact the `val` has the same name before and after the asm instruction doesn't mean that it is in the same location.  An example where `0` hurts -- if you have a function `u32 fn(int ign, u32 val) { asm(...); return val; }`.  With `0` this will be 3 instructions (rev+mov+ret), and without it will be just rev+ret.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  It is not like the OPs code though.  I definitely find it easier to understand, when the input and output are the same to use the "0".  I just tried this with the OPs code and gcc 4.8.2 and the code is identical for both.  Mainly because in his example, `int32hex` and `binhex` have `val` in the same register (R0).  The "0" annotation discounts that `rev` can be used as a *swap+move*, that is certainly true.  However, gcc 4.8.2 **can** use the same registers with your annotation so it is probably always better from a code generation perspective.